Interpretation of perpendendicularity of paths

Two particles are oscillating along two close parallel  straight lines
side by side, with the same frequency  and amplitudes. They pass each
other, moving in  opposite directions when their displacement is half
of the amplitude. The mean positions of the two  particles lie on a
straight line perpendicular to the  paths of the two particles. The
phase difference is (NEET 2010)

This can be solved by calculating the phase difference between the equations of the two particles
$$\phi_1 - \phi_2 = \frac{5\pi}{6}-\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{4\pi}{6}=\frac{2\pi}{6}$$
I am trying the perpendicularity part of the sentence below. What exactly is perpendicular to what?

The mean positions of the two  particles lie on a straight line
perpendicular to the  paths of the two particles.



It just means the centre points of the two oscillators are lined up.

I do not understand the "perpendicular to the paths" part. Where does the perpendicularity come in?

The paths are the two vertical lines, and the mean positions lie on the horizontal line. The vertical and horizontal line are perpendicular.
